# How to set the character encoding for a file in VIM

Tags: vim, encoding

I'm using `:set fileencoding=utf-8` and the file is saved correctly, but the next time I open it, I get garbled characters and `:set fileencoding?` says the option isn't set.

From the docs I understand that I shouldn't touch the `encoding` option.

What's the correct way of specifying an encoding for a file in VIM?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use

```
set fileencodings=utf-8
```

(with an s at the end) which can contain a list of different encodings.  Vim will try the encodings listed, from left to right, until one works and it will set fileencoding to that encoding.  If none work then fileencoding is set to an empty string which will result in default behavior.

Also it would probably make sense to add that to your vimrc so you aren't constantly doing that.

Answer (score 25):

You should set `fileencodings` to the different encodings vim should try when opening a file, for example:

```
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
```

From `:help fileencodings`:

> This is a list of character encodings
>   considered when starting to edit
>   an existing file.  When a file is read, Vim tries to use the first
>   mentioned character encoding.  If an error is detected, the next one
>   in the list is tried.  When an encoding is found that works,
>   `fileencoding` is set to it.

You best put these settings in your `.vimrc` file so that you don't have to input them manually each time you start vim.

Answer (score 13):

You can put that directive into a comment in the file:

```
# vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
```

Comment: Nice, is this similar to the "-*-" -syntax?

Comment: @Jonas: I'm afraid I don't know anything about that.

Comment: I believe "-*-" syntax is for Emacs?

Comment: It's also used for `Python` scripts, although I believe the idea originates in Emacs.

Answer (score 12):

If vim doesn't display your file correctly when opened specify encoding with
**:set encoding=utf8**

Answer (score 4):

I read many thread about VIM encoding. I find that the most important trick is:
Before open the file ,you should open VIM first, then use the command:
**edit ++enc= filename.ext**
It can handle most questions about encoding and fileencoding.

the key points include:

1. You must display the charset correctly! without correct display, any other operations may cause unrecoverable issue.
2. after the file is displayed correctly, if needed , you can 
   ":set fileencoding=UTF-8"
   : write"
   to let VIM can always display it correctly.

Because I am not an English mother tongue user, I think my way is able to be validate.

Comment: You can reload a file you have already opened using 
:e ++enc=<encoding> (see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Reloading_a_file_using_a_different_encoding). No need to start vim first without opening the file.

Answer (score 4):

- open:

  ```
  vim ~/.vimrc
  ```
- add:

  ```
  set fileencodings=utf-8
  set encoding=utf-8
  ```
- save and close by typing:

  ```
  :wq
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two functions to your .vimrc file:

```
function! Latin()   
  silent! exe "e! ++enc=latin1" 
endfunction

function! Utf8()
  silent! exe "e! ++enc=utf-8" 
endfunction
```

And then call the functions this way type Esc and

```
:call Latin() 
    
:call Utf8()
```