# Strange characters appearing in vim after quitting from the file

Tags: vim

This might be quite weird for you. After I press `:wq` and reopen my file strange characters appear like this `@t += 1^[[>1;4402;0c` , rather it should just be `@t += 1`. Program is not throwing any error or exceptions.Also these characters don't show up when I open the file in gedit or sublime text.They are also hooked on a particular line irrespective of code or any content on that line.Any help?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in vim or in your terminal emulator. Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu terminal

Comment: Looks somehow like an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Which bytes does the file physically contain? Can you post the output of `od -c yourfile`?

Comment: results of `od -c .vimrc` [here](https://pastebin.com/xQfVAeH9)

Answer (score 1):

Error might be because of encoding scheme. Try UTF-8.

For setting UTF-8 as default encoding scheme [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1174871/3185670)

Comment: UTF-8 is set as default encoding scheme, still persists in every file I create.